# What is the simplest way of writing below logic

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have logic like this .

```
if( (value1 !="0" || value2!="0") && value3=="0")
{
  value3=string.empty;
}
```

Similarly

```
  if( (value2 !="0" || value3!="0") && value1=="0")
    {
      value1=string.empty;
    }

 if( (value1 !="0" || value3!="0") && value2=="0")
    {
      value2=string.empty;
    }
```

What is the best way to write above logic using linq ? with out repeating logic

My idea is push them through collection dictionary . But not exactly sure of logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with one line function:

```
bool test(string[] orConds, string andCond, string val) => orConds.Any(s => s != val) && andCond == val;
```

Usage:

```
const string check = "0";
string s1 = "0", s2 = "1", s3 = "0";

if (test(new[] { s1, s2 }, s3, check))
  s3 = check;
```